# confusion about the definition of the permutation action on a multilinear function

Tags: manifolds, group-actions, symmetric-groups

I am reading the book by Loring W. Tu, `An introduction to manifolds'.

on page 23, he defines the permutation action on multilinear functions as

$$ (\sigma f)(v_{1}, v_{2}, \ldots, v_{k} ) = f(v_{\sigma(1)}, v_{\sigma(2)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma(k)}) . $$

He verified that this is indeed an action of the permutation group $S_k$ on multilinear function. That is, he veried that $(\tau\sigma) f = \tau(\sigma f )$.

I can follow the proof step by step, but I am still a little bit uneasy with the way of action.

Why is it $\sigma$, but not '$\sigma^{-1}$', on the right hand side?

We know that if a group $G$ acts on a set $M$, then the induced action of $G$ on the functions on $M$ is

$$ (g F)(x) = F(g^{-1}x) .$$

Here on the RHS, we have $g^{-1}$.

Comment: I think the reason is that you have the composition of **two** functions here. One function is obviously $f$. But the other, somewhat hidden, function is the map $\{ 1, 2, \dots, n \} \to V$ ($V$ being the implied vector space) given by $i \mapsto v_{i}$. So you have two inversions, which cancel each other.

Comment: To spell this out, $\tau(v_{1}, \dots, v_{n}) = (v_{\tau^{-1}(1)}, \dots, v_{\tau^{-1}(n)})$. Then $(\sigma f) (v_{1}, \dots, v_{n}) = f(\sigma^{-1}(v_{1}, \dots, v_{n})) = f(v_{\sigma(1)}, \dots, v_{\sigma(n)})$.